# Как в css задать два разных времени транзишена для двух теней?

Tags: css, css3, css-animation, transition

Как в css задать два разных времени транзишена для двух теней? чтобы две тени начали анимироваться одновременно, но продолжительность их анимации была разная?

```
  .game-item {
    transition box-shadow 0.3s, box-shadow 1s
  }

  .game-item:hover {
    box-shadow inset 0 0 0 0.15em blue, 0 0.5em 1em red
  }
```

чтобы первая тень появлялась за 0.3 секунды а вторая за 1 секунду

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Очевидный ответ: ни как. Семантика css достаточно убога и не позволяет описать это, и нужно делать костыли, врапперы, javascript. Css не позволяет задать разный транзишен для множественных свойств, по этому транзишен для свойства box-shadow применяется глобально, сколько бы там не было теней.

**Вот костыль с псевдоклассом:**

```css
.game-item {
 margin: 40px auto;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: pink;
 position: relative;
 transition: box-shadow 3s;
}

.game-item:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.game-item:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 4em red;
}

.game-item:hover:before {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-item"></div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' Нет, здесь нужны костыли, потому что css убог и не достаточно гибок чтобы задать транзишены для множественных свойств. Именно по этому мой пример работает, а ваш  нет. Так же я задаю вопросы четко и предельно понятно любому нормальному человеку, вы просто не поняли его в силу своих особенностей, вам следует быть внимательнее.

Comment: Sevastopol' нет ни какой логической связи между краткой записью css свойств, и длинной. Это ни как не относится к вопросу. Тем не менее, вы не правы, нельзя задать разное время анимации для множественных теней без костылей (так как css убог). Если можно то докажите.

Comment: @Sevastopol' я повторю еще раз, меньше слов больше дела, покажите мне КОД который сделает разную длительность анимации у двух теней одного элемента. Проверим ваши слова на практике

Answer (score 1):

> очевидный ответ: ни как, синтаксис css настолько убог что не позволяет
>   описать это, и нужно делать костыли, врапперы, javascript, но вдруг
>   кто-то умудрился сделать это на чистом css? =)
>   **Алексей Соснин**

Не правда, нисколько синтаксис `css` не убог. Это решается, например, простой анимацией с помощью правила `@keyframes`. Смотрите пример. Обе анимации начинаются одновременно. Анимация появления вашей первой тени длится `0.5s`, а второй `3s`. Может показаться, что анимация появления второй тени запаздывает (начинается не одновременно с первой), но это вовсе не так, так как ее продолжительность превышает первую в три раза. Поэтому создается такое ложное ощущение.

> ...А ДИЗЛАЙКАЕТ МЕНЯ...
> **Алексей Соснин**

P.S. Алексей Соснин, читал в Вашем вопросе все Ваши оскорбления в мой адрес. Простите, но Вы не правы. Как я Вам и писал в комментариях, я никогда никому не ставил и не ставлю минусы. Это касается ответов. Что касается вопросов, то это бывает очень даже крайне редко. И кстати, Вашему вопросу и Вашему ответу я минусы не ставил, и это легко проверить. Поэтому, пожалуйста, постарайтесь впредь, оставляя свои комментарии, не быть столь эмоциональным в своих высказываниях, не употреблять ненормативную лексику, а тем более не оскорблять участников сообщества. Благодарю за понимание!

```css
.game-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.game-item:hover {
  animation: shadow 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes shadow {
  0% { box-shadow: 0 0 0 0em blue, 0 0 0 0em red; }
  15% { box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em blue, 0 0 0 1em red; }
  100% { box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em blue, 0 0 0 4em red; }
}
```

```html
<div class="game-item"></div>
```

Comment: к сожалению ваши две анимации тени запускаются не одновременно, они должны запускаться одновременно, словно два разных свойства, а дурейшен должен быть разный ^_^

Comment: В  хроме синяя тень появляется мгновенно, а не плавно, разве нет?

Comment: за  0.3s секунды, братан... *facepalm*

Comment: в моем вопросе и так все четко понятно, "транзишен за 0.3s" означает дурейшен транзишена, но ни как не делей, потому что делей выражался бы как "за 0.3s до" а раз слово до не использутеся значит имеется ввиду дурейшен а не делей

Comment: нет, ваша синяя тень появляется мгновенно, а не за 0.3 секунды, вы просто не замечаете этого, но заметите если увеличите время с 0.3 до 3

Comment: @Sevastopol' так - только оба ответа правильные и это не кастыли -

Comment: @MaximLensky его ответ вообще не правильный, так как он вручную расчитывает промежуточное значение тени, и не может использовать разные нелинейные изинги. А мой ответ правильный, но к остыль.